# Kubernetes NFS persistent volumes permission denied

Tags: docker, kubernetes, permission-denied, nfs, persistent-volumes

I have an application running over a POD in Kubernetes.
I would like to store some output file logs on a persistent storage volume.

In order to do that, I created a volume over the NFS and bound it to the POD through the related volume claim.
When I try to write or accede the shared folder I got a "permission denied" message, since the NFS is apparently read-only.

The following is the json file I used to create the volume:

```
{
      "kind": "PersistentVolume",
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "task-pv-test"
      },
      "spec": {
        "capacity": {
          "storage": "10Gi"
        },
        "nfs": {
          "server": <IPAddress>,
          "path": "/export"
        },
        "accessModes": [
          "ReadWriteMany"
        ],
        "persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy": "Delete",
        "storageClassName": "standard"
      }
    }
```

The following is the POD configuration file

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: volume-test
spec:
    volumes:
        -   name: task-pv-test-storage
            persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: task-pv-test-claim
    containers:
        -   name: volume-test
            image: <ImageName>
            volumeMounts:
            -   mountPath: /home
                name: task-pv-test-storage
                readOnly: false
```

Is there a way to change permissions?

---

UPDATE

Here are the PVC and NFS config:

PVC:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-test-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

NFS CONFIG

```
{
  "kind": "Pod",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "nfs-client-provisioner-557b575fbc-hkzfp",
    "generateName": "nfs-client-provisioner-557b575fbc-",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/nfs-client-provisioner-557b575fbc-hkzfp",
    "uid": "918b1220-423a-11e8-8c62-8aaf7effe4a0",
    "resourceVersion": "27228",
    "creationTimestamp": "2018-04-17T12:26:35Z",
    "labels": {
      "app": "nfs-client-provisioner",
      "pod-template-hash": "1136131967"
    },
    "ownerReferences": [
      {
        "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
        "kind": "ReplicaSet",
        "name": "nfs-client-provisioner-557b575fbc",
        "uid": "3239b14a-4222-11e8-8c62-8aaf7effe4a0",
        "controller": true,
        "blockOwnerDeletion": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "spec": {
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "nfs-client-root",
        "nfs": {
          "server": <IPAddress>,
          "path": "/Kubernetes"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "nfs-client-provisioner-token-fdd2c",
        "secret": {
          "secretName": "nfs-client-provisioner-token-fdd2c",
          "defaultMode": 420
        }
      }
    ],
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "nfs-client-provisioner",
        "image": "quay.io/external_storage/nfs-client-provisioner:latest",
        "env": [
          {
            "name": "PROVISIONER_NAME",
            "value": "<IPAddress>/Kubernetes"
          },
          {
            "name": "NFS_SERVER",
            "value": <IPAddress>
          },
          {
            "name": "NFS_PATH",
            "value": "/Kubernetes"
          }
        ],
        "resources": {},
        "volumeMounts": [
          {
            "name": "nfs-client-root",
            "mountPath": "/persistentvolumes"
          },
          {
            "name": "nfs-client-provisioner-token-fdd2c",
            "readOnly": true,
            "mountPath": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"
          }
        ],
        "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
        "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
        "imagePullPolicy": "Always"
      }
    ],
    "restartPolicy": "Always",
    "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
    "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
    "serviceAccountName": "nfs-client-provisioner",
    "serviceAccount": "nfs-client-provisioner",
    "nodeName": "det-vkube-s02",
    "securityContext": {},
    "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
    "tolerations": [
      {
        "key": "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready",
        "operator": "Exists",
        "effect": "NoExecute",
        "tolerationSeconds": 300
      },
      {
        "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
        "operator": "Exists",
        "effect": "NoExecute",
        "tolerationSeconds": 300
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": {
    "phase": "Running",
    "hostIP": <IPAddress>,
    "podIP": "<IPAddress>,
    "startTime": "2018-04-17T12:26:35Z",
    "qosClass": "BestEffort"
  }
}
```

I have just removed some status information from the nfs config to make it shorter

Comment: Can you post your nfs config and your pvc?

Comment: @fragae, Did u found the solution? same issue for me too..

Comment: @LokanadhamMotumarri, setting the SecurityContext with the right group ID in the pod configuration file worked for me

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you set the proper `securityContext` for the pod configuration you can make sure the volume is mounted with proper permissions.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000 
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-test-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-test-claim
  containers:
  - name: demo
    image: example-image
    volumeMounts:
    - name: task-pv-test-storage
      mountPath: /data/demo
```

In the above example the storage will be mounted at `/data/demo` with 2000 group id, which is set by `fsGroup`. By setting the fsGroup all processes of the container will also be part of the supplementary group ID 2000, thus you should have access to the mounted files.

You can read more about pod security context here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/

Comment: that example wont use nfs. So there /data/demo has 2000 gid.
But, if we change the PV to NFS, there also we are getting permission error.

Comment: Tried it also with NFS and it didn't work with fsGroup.
Probably because of this issue https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/issues/260

Comment: Why do you need to find of the users. The docs clearly states: ...Since fsGroup field is specified, all processes of the container are also part of the supplementary group ID 2000. The owner for volume /data/demo and any files created in that volume will be Group ID 2000.

Comment: You are right, I have updated the answer.

Comment: idk man there seem to be evidence that `fsGroup` doesn't work for NFS, see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/issues/260

Answer (score 19):

Thanks to 白栋天 for the [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50170158/4794841).
For instance, if the pod securityContext is set to:

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 1000
  fsGroup: 1000
```

you would ssh to the NFS host and run

```
chown 1000:1000 -R /some/nfs/path
```

If you do not know the user:group or many pods will mount it, you can run

```
chmod 777 -R /some/nfs/path
```

Comment: From a security perspective, I am not sure chmod 777 is a good approach - BUT it was the solution for me at least (after many frustrating hours). The funny thing though is, that with dynamic/managed provisioning (https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/nfs-client) this is not an issue at all. Anyway, thank you for the proposal, it will suffice for my homelab :-)

Comment: @gimlichael It seems that the dynamic provisoner does exactly this, chmod 777: https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/blob/master/nfs-client/cmd/nfs-client-provisioner/provisioner.go#L72

Comment: @gimlichael if you set the "runAsUser: 1000" like in the example above then chmod 755 should work. If you *only* set "fsGroup: 1000" without also setting the user like in the previous answers then you'll at least need 770 (or 775) since the user will only run with the specified GID.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to get to the nfs storage, and chmod 777, or chown with the user id in your volume-test container

Comment: I tried to change the owner using the user id from the volume-test container config file, but I got an invalid user message.  The id looks like: "uid": "923ca461-4ec9-11e8-8ab3-8aaf7effe4a0". Is that the right one?

Comment: the user id is determined by the USER which exist in the end of  dockerfile, default is set to 0(root), if u dont know the user id (which could be get by execute "id" in container), then just use chmod +R 777

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone downvoted this. This question is specific to NFS and apparently as pointed out above the NFS host needs to have the permissions set as Kubernetes cannot manage the NFS host's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused from how you're trying to get things done, in any case if I'm understanding you correctly try this example:

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      namespace: kube-system
      labels:
        k8s-app: something
        monitoring: something
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

And then maybe an init container do do something:

```
initContainers:
        - name: prometheus-init
          image: /something/bash-alpine:1.5
          command:
            - chown
            - -R
            - 65534:65534
            - /data
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
```

or is it the volumeMounts you're missing out on:

```
volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/config
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
```

My last comment would be to take note on containers, I think you're only allowed to write in `/tmp` or was it just for CoreOS? I'd have to look that up.

Answer (score -9):

Have you checked the permissions of directory ? Make sure read access is available to all.