# File ownership and permissions from processes inside the pod's containers in Kubernetes

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes

Based on the [official](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) docs:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 3000
    fsGroup: 2000
  volumes:
  - name: sec-ctx-vol
    emptyDir: {}
  containers:
  - name: sec-ctx-demo
    image: busybox
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 1h" ]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: sec-ctx-vol
      mountPath: /data/demo
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

> Since fsGroup field is specified, all processes of the container are
> also part of the supplementary group ID 2000. The owner for volume
> /data/demo and any files created in that volume will be Group ID 2000.

However, it seems the document is not accurate enough. I found a lot of bug reports about different tools and frameworks, as well as [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156124/kubernetes-nfs-persistent-volumes-permission-denied) at SO, which suggest that it's not as simple as that.

Now, I myself have a similar situation. I have Wordpress deployed in GKE and its `wp-content` dir mounted as Persistent Volume. I set `fsGroup` `65534` for the entire Pod, which according to the docs should enforce supplementary group on all processes inside all containers.
But I don't think that it can be enforced regardless of how processes are spawned. It probably even contradict Unix security architecture.

Back to my example: I can't store new files from Wordpress UI into wp-content folder because the permission is denied.
I entered Wordpress container and here's what I see:

```
131111 drwxr-sr-x  4    65533 65533  4096 Dec  9 22:28 rev-f2380fe737e72b1749f98b69fca3e5a739502313
```

(`rev` dir is symlinked to by `wp-content`. I use `git-sync` for that).
Now, I check the processes:

```
root@my-wp-deployment-64647c8bcb-9hv7j:/var/www/html# ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.0  0.8 238516 34392 ?        Ss   Dec09   0:03 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
root         118  0.0  0.0   3868  3276 pts/0    Ss+  Dec09   0:00 /bin/bash
www-data     843  0.0  2.8 342704 114056 ?       S    09:39   0:01 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data     855  0.0  2.4 334936 98624 ?        S    09:39   0:01 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data     857  0.0  2.6 342484 108112 ?       S    09:39   0:02 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data     859  0.0  2.6 335032 106760 ?       S    09:39   0:02 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data     932  0.0  2.4 334888 98976 ?        S    10:33   0:01 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data     934  0.0  2.8 345308 116380 ?       S    10:33   0:01 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data     938  0.0  2.4 337084 99040 ?        S    10:33   0:01 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data     940  0.0  2.5 339356 104144 ?       S    10:33   0:02 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data     946  0.0  2.1 328920 87932 ?        S    10:33   0:00 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
www-data     966  0.0  2.1 326644 84796 ?        S    10:56   0:00 apache2 -DFOREGROUND
root         975  0.0  0.0   3868  3180 pts/1    Ss   11:06   0:00 /bin/bash
root         989  0.0  0.0   7640  2708 pts/1    R+   11:14   0:00 ps aux
```

And now I aslo check user's group affiliation:

```
root@my-wp-deployment-64647c8bcb-9hv7j:/var/www/html# groups root
root : root
root@my-wp-deployment-deployment-64647c8bcb-9hv7j:/var/www/html# groups www-data
www-data : www-data
```

As I see, some of the users are not associated with `65534` and they are the once that initiate new processes.

Where's the catch? Am I missing something or is Kubernetes doc not accurate? Or both?:)

Comment: I see several issues with your question. First is that `groups` cmd shows only regular groups and it won't show you the suplementary groups. Try `ps a -o user,pid,ppid,supgid,group,cmd` to see supgrp of processes. Second is that `rev-xxx` dir has user and group of 65533 and you mentioned setting fsgroup 65534, but I assume its a typo. Third, looking at the permisions `drwxr-sr-x` i looks like permissions for group is read only, so I am not supprised you cannot write to rev dorectory.

Comment: Can you confirm that this is the case? Or correct me if I am missing something

Comment: @Matt, it must be a typo, but I will need to check it more thoroughly in terms of the last commits.

Comment: As for the extended command with a check: root         118       0 65533                root     /bin/bash;
root        4739       0 65533                root     /bin/bash;
root        4744    4739 65533                root     ps a -o user,pid,ppid,supgid,group,cmd

Comment: So, yes, the 65533group is there. Thanks! But it's only root. What about www-data?

Comment: Try `ps aux -o user,pid,ppid,supgid,group,cmd` to see all processes